# alternate other OS for android development

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I am using `Ubuntu OS` for  kernel development, device driver, and Android application development. But in Ubuntu I am facing a freezing screen problem so I am not able to work on. This is OS specific problem and other people also getting this problem.
 Can anyone suggest me except Ubuntu what are other similar OS so that I can proceed my work. How is fedora and Open source Suse?

Comment: Most of the freeze screen issues in ubuntu is due to upgrading the OS from previous version to current/latest version.. Just try with afresh install... Fedora is also good.. In case you wanna shift to a new OS.

Comment: @anil-  i installed ubuntu 11.04 and 12.10. some people suggested me to install ubuntu 11.10, i heard it is stable os. isnt is?

Answer (score 0):

any .04 is a LTS and you can use that.. I suggest 11.04 if you interested in learning kernel development... Even Android OS kernel development documentation recommends 11.04 for Kernel Dev..

Comment: thank you but 11.04 and 12.10 in both i am facing this freezing screen problem. i have only option of 11.10 which is to be verified. so i am searching other alternate options.